# Why normalized EXR renderings of surface Normals look different than PNG renderings?

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, rendering, blender

I render surface Normals using Cycles and store the results in EXR format. The values in the EXR format are within the range of `[-1, 1]` meaning that I cannot directly store the values in a PNG file. Here's how I read the `.exr` files and store store the values in a `numpy` array:

```
import OpenEXR, array, Imath
exrFile = OpenEXR.InputFile('normal.exr')
FLOAT = Imath.PixelType(Imath.PixelType.FLOAT)
(RGB) = [array.array('f', exrFile.channel(Chan, FLOAT)).tolist() for Chan in ("R", "G", "B") ]
normalNPArray = np.array(RGB)
normalNPArray = normalNPArray.reshape((3, resolution, resolution))
```

I normalize the values as follow and store the surface Normal as a PNG image:

```
normalNPArray += 1
normalNPArray /= 2
normalNPArray *= 255
normalNPArray = normalNPArray.astype(np.uint8)
im = Image.fromarray(normalNPArray.transpose(1, 2, 0), mode='RGB')
im.save('temp.png')
```

Here's what I get after opening the stored image:
[image]

If I simply ignore the values below zero (remove/comment the first two lines) I get the following:
[image]

However, if I directly store the surface Normal as a PNG image instead of EXR I get the following:

[image]

I wonder, how can I get a visualization that looks like the PNG rendering? How does Blender normalize the values?

Comment: Why not exported directly into PNG?

Comment: @Ricardo Well I need to do my analysis with the raw values but I alao need to be able to visualize the Normals the way Blender outputs them.

Comment: Your second image looks wrong, while third is what second is supposed to be (cutout lower than 0). First one appears to be correct remapping though.

Comment: @keltar Yes I was thinking the second one should look exactly like the third one. Don't know why this does not happen.

Comment: @Amir it sure does looks like wrong calc. My quick test `(np.array([-1])*255).astype(np.uint8)` gives `1`, which suggests numpy type conversion uses overflow rather than cutout. (I have never used numpy so I don't know if it is documented)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [keltar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/744720/keltar) mentioned in one of the comments, It turns out Numpy does not automatically set the negative values to `0` when casting the array type to `uint8`. For instance, suppose I have a numpy array as follow:

```
array([  46.73017823, -250.31618571, -247.44416527,   97.52841554,
       -204.92988386,  191.09452493,  103.15708521,  -86.10470495,
         46.211924  , -195.30653599,  240.44499889, -169.42729244,
        210.44996545, -182.04892973, -166.20581924, -221.11524425,
        164.79367242, -199.80888341,   94.1786936 ,   43.45477102])
```

I was expecting that doing `normalNPArray = normalNPArray.astype(np.uint8)` will automatically set the negative values to `0` since `uint8` does not naturally support negative values. However, casting the array as `np.uint8` gives me the following:

```
array([ 46,   6,   9,  97,  52, 191, 103, 170,  46,  61, 240,  87, 210,
            74,  90,  35, 164,  57,  94,  43], dtype=uint8)
```

Doing `normalNPArray[normalNPArray < 0] = 0` and then casting the array to `np.uint8` will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a friend that helps me with this i hope is useful to you:

When making normal maps for a renderer or shader the following needs to be considered :

1. The "space" in which the normals are defined. That can be world space, object space, or tangent space.
2. The ordering of the axes the renderer expects [ x, y, z ] vs  [x , -y, z] ,etc.
3. The range can be [0,1] or [-1,1].
4. And possibly how Alphas are handled.

One can read about the format and figure it out. Or simply get an existing normal map the works and figure out the format visually. For example, if the working maps look light blue, they are most likely in tangent space whereas world space has more pure reds, greens, and blues.

Most people use tangent space normal maps because it allows for deformations. I believe Blender gives you the option for all three [HERE](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/vector/normal_map.html)

Note:
I check the image that you store (image 1) and the background is not 0. Should be zero if the original image has -1 background. So you are doing something wrong in the code. It would be pretty helpful if you post the EXR image so i can do some test.

Comment: Why would original image have -1 on empty spaces if it have nothing there? (0,0,0) at least describes it as "no normal here" (vector length==0), -1 would be just a lie. Also your link (like the most of answer) is about using normal maps, not generating them (which can still be done in blender via 'baking'), and even that is quite different from what question seems to be - performing regular render from camera but only using normals result.

Comment: Thanks for the information but this does not answer my question. Also, if the background was -1 in the original Numpy array, how would it become 125, 125, 125 in the "normalized" version (looks gray)? If the background was -1 the normalized image would show a black background.

Comment: That is what I am saying should be zero so you are might doing something wrong, if you give me the original image (EXR) that would be very helpful for me so i can do some test on it